# {{MEDIA_URL}} with Django and Ember.js

Tags: django, ember.js

I have the following handlebars template:

```
{% handlebars "header" %}
<div class="header row-fluid">
  <div class="logo"> <a href="index.html"><span>Welcome!</span><span class="icon"></span></a> </div>
  <div class="top_right">
    <ul class="nav nav_menu">
      <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle administrator" id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
        <div class="title"><span class="name">George</span><span class="subtitle">Awesome Developer</span></div>
        <span class="icon"><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}images/dashboard/thumbnail_george.jpg"></span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- End top-right --> 
</div>
{% endhandlebars %}
```

The problem is that the {{MEDIA_URL}} is of course out of context here so I cannot render my images. I tried using bindAttr for the src but the problem is still there. How do I go about solving this problem.

On a side note, this template is static in the sense that the only reason I'm using handlebars is to use the {{action}} helper of Ember to transition to a new state upon clicking on one of these buttons. Is this the correct way to do it?

**UPDATE:** 
My temporary solution is that I have a mediaUrl property in my controller and I've hardcoded the media url. However, this is not desirted as the media url can change at anytime at server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be best off having the server process the template and insert the correct MEDIA_URL before sending it to the client. The only other way I can think of is to do a separate query to the server to get that URL before rendering.